# OOP question: how to associate additional, arbitrary information with some items

Tags: oop

I have some hierarchy of items, what is the best way to store additional information about them, when they are used in some **different context**?

For example, I have some items and some of them are products in some shop, I want to store additional fields, needed for the shop, like price, availability etc. I don't want to store this information in the items directly, because they can be used in many different contexts at the same time. Or some item is a birthday present, I want to store some other additional information like who is gonna get the present etc and associate it with this item.
What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What [wiki says about oop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming):

> OOP (Object-oriented programming) is a programming paradigm based on
> the concept of "objects", which can contain data and code: **data in the
> form of fields (often known as attributes or properties)**, and code, in
> the form of procedures (often known as methods).

So, I do not think that it is good idea to separate additional information from its context. If you do it, then your code will become more complicated.

Comment: But that's the point, a certain thing can have different properties that are important for that context. For example Tom Hanks can be just a person (general context), an actor, a husband. I want him to have different properties in each context, without relying on built-in inheritance of the programming language (because I need more flexibility for data for my purposes). And I want Tom Hanks - the actor to somehow point to Tom Hanks - the person, to simulate inheritance. So, basically want to take Tom Hanks - the person and add additional attributes to him and use it for "actor" context.